# Profiling Java app : Cumulative times for methods recursively

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

Consider this producer-consumer code using a `ArrayBlockingQueue` : I want to find out 
a. How much total time is consumed by `put()`/`take()` overall ?
b. how much total time is spent by the `put()` and `take()` calls in waiting ? Blocked ?

Taking a snapshot in VisualVM only shows upto a depth of run() , but not the `put()` / `take()` calls. Any idea how to get these times ?

In general , how do I get cumulative running times for all methods recursively down from the `main()` ?

```
final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(QUEUE_SIZE);
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    exec.submit(new Runnable() {
        int i =0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(i++<NUM)
                try {
                    queue.put(i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });

    exec.submit(new Runnable() {
        int i =0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(i++<NUM)
                try {
                    queue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            consumerFinished.countDown();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the "CPU settings" that filter out all code belonging `java.*` packages. Check "Settings" on the "Sampler" tab and edit the "CPU settings" in a new preset. Presets are managed at the bottom of the CPU-settings tab.